# Calculate difference between two timestamps

Tags: node.js, timestamp, twitch, node-fetch, twitch-api

I'm using the twitch api and TMI.JS

I'm trying to fetch the timestamp of `followed_at`. The timestamp I got was `2021-12-25T15:49:57Z`, how would I go about getting the current timestamp, and then calculating the difference. So in this instance it would return `followername has been following streamername for 20 days 19 hours` (at the time of writing it's been 20 days and 19 hours since the `followed_at` timestamp.)

```
if (message.toLowerCase() === '!followage')  {
client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, does not work yet `)
  console.log(`${channel.id}`)
  console.log(`${tags['user-id']}`)
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users/follows?to_id=226395001&from_id=${tags['user-id']}`, { method: 'get', headers: {
    'Client-Id': 'cut out for a reason',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer cut out for a reason'
    
  }});
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data)
  if (data.data[0]) {
    client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, followed at ${data.data[0].followed_at}`)
    
  } else {
    client.say(channel, `You aren't followed!`)
  }
  }
  getData()
  




}
```

Above is my code for fetching it, and then sending it to the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
const followedAt = new Date('2021-12-25T15:49:57Z');
const currentDate = new Date();
const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - followedAt);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(diffTime + " milliseconds");
console.log(diffDays + " days");
```

And that's the way to get days and hours:

```
const followedAt = new Date('2021-12-25T15:49:57Z');
const currentDate = new Date();
const diffTime = Math.abs(currentDate - followedAt);
const diffTotalHours = Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)); 
const diffDays = Math.floor(diffTotalHours / 24);
const diffHoursWithoutDays = diffTotalHours % 24;

console.log(`${diffDays} days and ${diffHoursWithoutDays} hours`);
```

Comment: This sort of works, it gave me 21 days, but its actually 20 days and 21 hours, Math.ceil made it higher than it is in reality, how to make it put out "20 days and 21 hours"?

Comment: @hermes I've updated my answer, please check it